# How to change only one column table into dataframe with many columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pretty-print

I scraped some data online and save them in the notepad as text. Now I want to make analysis on these data but realized that there was only one column.

Since the text file was done in pretty table, I couldn't split the data.

```
The text file looks like this. 
                                                 0
0  +-------------+------+--------+---------+-----...
1  |  series id  | year | period |  value  | foot...
2  +-------------+------+--------+---------+-----...
3  | CUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M12   | 234.812 |     ...
4  | CUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M11   | 236.151 |     ...
```

Even the table looks like have five columns, but when I checked the shape, actually there was only one. 
Can anyone help how to transfer it into five columns in dataframe?

Comment: did you try using a sep, and headers option arguments in pandas.read_csv() option?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method to accomplish this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample text file (stored as a single string)
text = '''                                                 0
0  +-------------+------+--------+---------+
1  |  series id  | year | period |  value  |
2  +-------------+------+--------+---------+
3  | CUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M12   | 234.812 |
4  | CUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M11   | 236.151 |'''

# Parse the text file
lst = text.replace('+', '').replace('-', '').replace('|', '').split('\n')
new_lst = [lst[2]] + lst[4:] # Grab the data around the empty rows

# Build the data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(new_lst) # Create data frame from list
df = df[0].str.split(expand=True) # Split data into columns
df.columns = df.iloc[0,:] # Name the columns
df = df[1:] # Remove the first row
df = df[df.columns[1:]] # Remove the first column
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

```
0       series    id year   period value
0  CUUR0000SA0  2014  M12  234.812  None
1  CUUR0000SA0  2014  M11  236.151  None
```

You may have to tweak it just a little to work with your actual data.

You'll probably read in your text file like this:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

You can use `text = '\n'.join(lines)` and then proceed with the rest of the above script.